# Multiple inputs from user using Scanner and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to code a program which relies on user input to create students and their marks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Marks {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many students are there? ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    String [] student = new String[n];   

    for(int i = 0; i <student.length; i++){
        int nextI = i + 1;
        System.out.print("Enter name of student " + nextI + ": ");
        student[i] = sc.next();

}
```

My aim is to have the program prompt a message, "Enter marks:" after a user inputs the name of the student, but could not find any site/post to help me be able to do this.

Comment: If you want to store the total marks or marks in just one subject for each student, you need to create another 1-D array for marks. However, if each student can have more than one subjects, you need a 2-D array. Learn about Java Arrays from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have another array for marks and store the marks in the other array. Following code may help.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students are there? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String [] student = new String[n];   
        String [] marks =new String[n]; // use another array to store marks

        for(int i = 0; i <student.length; i++){
            int nextI = i + 1;
            System.out.print("Enter name of student " + nextI + ": ");
            student[i] = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Marks for " + student[i] + ": ");
            marks[i]= sc.next(); // store marks for the student
        }
        System.out.println("StudentName      Marks");
        for(int i=0;i<student.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(student[i]+"                "+marks[i]);
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
How many students are there? 2
Enter name of student 1: back
Enter Marks for back: 20
Enter name of student 2: door
Enter Marks for door: 30
StudentName      Marks
back                20
door                30
```

This can more effectively be done by `Map`. Explore yourself to learn more about `Map` try to implement the above code using `Map`

Comment: I'd suggest to create a `Student` class with id, name and mark attributes.